# Can I use nginx location and rewrite determine proxy_pass host?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am looking to do something along the lines of:

```
location ^/foo {
  rewrite ^/foo/(.+)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 break;
  proxy_pass http://$1:8080/$2
}
```

Is there some way to determine the proxy_pass URL based on a match from a rewrite statement?

The rough equivalent in Apache mod_rewrite would be:

```
RewriteRule ^/foo/(.+)/(.*)$ http://$1:8080/$2 [L,P]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the [rewrite module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#set) to extract and set a variable containing the value you want, and use that in the proxy directive.

```
if ($uri ~ ^/foo/(.+)/(.*)$) {
    set $part1 $1;
    set $part2 $2;
}
rewrite ^/foo/(.+)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 break;
proxy_pass http://$part1:8080/$part2;
```